# site navigation bootstrap toggle not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, navbar

Ok I am stumped.  I had my navbar and everything in it working, but then the client wanted some changes, and now, the toggle does not work.  It was completely gone, but now I have that back, but it will not open.  I have copied everything I could for different js files, and now I don't know which one is right.  I am including the code for the html and the js files.  I know I don't need them all, but now I don't know which ones I don't need.  This is Bootstrap v3.4.1

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default navbar-custom bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-menu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Feed My Sheep Ministries</a>
            </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav nav-link navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="about_us.shtml">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="statement_of_faith.shtml">Statement of Faith</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Church <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu open">
                    <li><a href="church_service.shtml">Church Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pastor_bruce_hood.shtml">Pastor Bruce Hood</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.shtml">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="calendar.shtml">Calendar of Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mens_recovery.shtml">Men's Recovery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Fresno_feed_hungry.shtml">Feed Fresno Hungry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="thrift_store.shtml">Thrift Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fairs_carnivals.shtml">Fairs and Carnivals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="car_bike_shows.shtml">Bike Shows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="car_show.shtml">Car Shows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="March_against_Meth.shtml">March Against Methamphetamine</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
                <li><a href="prayer.shtml">Prayer</a></li>
                <li><a href="eternal_life.shtml">Eternal Life</a></li>                
                <li><a href="donations.shtml">Give</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.shtml">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
```

```
   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script>
      !function ($) {
        $(function(){
          // carousel demo
          $('#myCarousel').carousel()
        })
      }(window.jQuery)
    </script>
    <script src="../assets/js/holder/holder.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not use the two-time same jquery library

```
jquery.min.js"
jquery.js
```